# Zoom (magnifying glass) effect in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create Magnifying Glass App very similar to build in in OS X (Mountain Lion).
I'm wondering how can I acheive this effect, using which frameworks?

[image]

What do you think, could it be a custom cursor? The image displayed in this rectange is just zoomed portion of backgound-spapped screen? I think that kind of implementation can run sluggish, and it could be difficult to change cursor whole System not only in "zooming" application.

Or maby it is use some quartz functionality is not known for me :)

I found one thing tha is interesting about Apples implementation (build in OS X), when I enter in zoom-mode and do a ScreenShot using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and next <kbd>Space</kbd> the image captured is like that:

[image]

With out any content of screen only the border of zooming area. So it tells me that it is some kind of transparent window abowe the screen but it is not taking over the focus.

Have you got any idea how to do that ?